# Как настроить мультисайт вордпресса на работу с подпапками?

Tags: wordpress

Нужно настроить мультисайт со структоруй на подпапках. Сервер на nginx.
Схема доменов - domain.com/ru, domain.com/en, ...

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в `wp-config.php` добавить:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
```

А в ваш конфиг для nginx:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;
}
```